# Sid.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made some changes to my previously working XHTML document to better organise the Javascript, and now Sid.js is having a fit when it attempts to append Javascript documents to the head.

In Chrome I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
```

On this line in [Sid.js](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/sidjs-load-javascript-and-stylesheets-on-demand)

```
scope.appendChild(node);
```

The problem is that

```
scope = (scope ? (scope == 'body' ? body : head) : (type == 'js' ? body : head));
```

is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved js files into body and it's fixed. Seems hacky.